# Al oprimir un botón que abra la aplicación de Mesengger desde mi aplicación

Tags: android-studio

Ya intente el siguiente código.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.messenger", 
PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener este comportamiento solo es necesario agregar el nombre del paquete de la aplicaciones de messenger.

> intent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");

Si quieres agregar un texto a la app para envío puedes agregar las lineas siguiente

> intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Texto a enviar");//Texto a enviar
>
> intent.setType("text/plain");//tipo de contenido extra

También tienes que asegurarte que la app este instalada en el celular para que no se lance una excepción inesperada.

El código completo quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Texto a enviar");
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");

try{
   startActivity(intent);
}catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
   Toast.makeText(this,
       "No encontramos la aplicación en tu dispositivo inténtalo luego.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public void messenger(View view) {
        Intent intent= new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");

```
    try{
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "No encontramos la aplicación en tu dispositivo inténtalo luego.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```